# How to send a JSON request with JSONObject as parameter?

Tags: json, delphi

I have a restful application-server built in Delphi XE4, and all of my JSON methods with a complex parameter like a JSONObject are **received** as a nil or empty object. I've read many tutorials but I still don't know why it don't works.

I'm testing my application-server with a tool from Chrome Browser, called "Advanced rest client app".

**Important facts:** If I have a client built in Delphi it works very well. If I try to consume GET requests with any clients, it works perfectly.

Same code:

```
function TServerMethods.cancelDeleteCheque(const aJSONObject: TJSONObject): TJSONObject;
var
  DMCheques: TDMCheques;
  sException: String;
begin
  try
    try
      sException := _EMPTY;
      result := TJSONObject.Create(nil);
      DMCheques := TDMCheques.GetInstance(nil);

      with aJSONObject do
      begin
        DMCheques.AddFilter(Format(' (CDCHENUMERO = %s) AND (NUMEROBANCO = %s) ', [QuotedStr(TJSONString(Get(0).JSONValue).Value),
          QuotedStr(TJSONString(Get(1).JSONValue).Value)]));
        DMCheques.cdsprincipal.Open;
        DMCheques.cdsPrincipal.Delete;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        sException := E.Message;
    end;
  finally
    if sException <> _EMPTY then
      result.AddPair(_EXCEPTION, TJSONString.Create(sException));

    if Assigned(DMCheques) then
      FreeAndNil(DMCheques);
  end;
end;
```

I get this message error: "Project AppServer.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0069b470: read of address 0x0000000c'." when I try to access the aJSONObject parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, sometimes you pass `nil` for `aJSONObject` and then wonder why you get an access violation when you try to access it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to pass a valid JSON object with two keys (e.g {'cheque':23487, 'banco':'001'}).

Look this pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw8lW.jpg

Comment: Then what do you mean by "like a JSONObject are passed as a nil or empty object."? Either way, if there's a chance that `aJSONObject` might not be assigned (`nil`), then you should do a check `if Assigned(aJSONObject) then ... ` just in case.

Comment: I did the correction. Sorry. I meant "receive" instead of "passed". Yes, I can try check if the object is nil, but I want to pass a valid object, look this pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw8lW.jpg.

Comment: On another note, I'm a bit skeptical about creating / returning an object as the result. Are you making sure it gets free'd afterward?

Comment: Thanks by this note. How the best way to send back the result?

Comment: Not sure, that's up to you, but your access violation is the problem at hand. The issue is most likely that `aJSONObject` is not assigned.

Comment: Wait, does this `TJSONObject` have a field named `DMCheques`? If so, then your `with` statement confuses the two.

Comment: No, I've already tried it before. The object `aJSONObject` it shown as `()` from "Delphi watch list".

Comment: Then your problem is likely outside of this function - somewhere, you're passing an empty object as `aJSONObject`. We can't see that code.

Comment: Thanks, but I not sure. As I said, if I consume that method `cancelDeleteCheque` from my client (built in Delphi) it works good, but not If I try from another technology. :/

Comment: Have you seen the image? I really don't understand the behavior of parameters `Attr1` and/or `HTTP/1.1`: `DeleteCheque/Attr1  HTTP/1.1`. I copied from @MarcoCantu white papper.

Comment: Testing from another technology (python):
`nfe = [{'CodigoUsuario':1,'CodigoEmpresa': 1}]`
`nfe_encoded = json.dumps(nfe)`
`url2 = 'http://localhost:88/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods/PutNF'`
`r2 = requests.put(url2, data=nfe_encoded)`

Answer (score 0):

If the sample JSON you provide in the comments is accurate then I think the problem is that your strings are **single-quoted** (').

The JSON specification stipulates the use of **double-quotes** ("), and this is what the Delphi XE4 JSON parser expects.  It is likely that the environments which are 'working" are applying the JSON specification less rigorously and are accepting single-quoted strings, which are valid JavaScript but not JSON.

i.e. for Delphi XE4 (and according to [json.org](http://json.org/)) this is not valid JSON:

```
[{'CodigoUsuario':1,'CodigoEmpresa': 1}]
```

Trying to parse this results in a NIL object since it does not represent a valid JSON value, which is probably why you end up with NIL being passed to your method.

For this to be accepted by Delphi XE4 you must **double-quote** encode the strings:

```
[{"CodigoUsuario":1,"CodigoEmpresa": 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Deltics. The DXE4 does that "conversion" automatically. When I debug my application I can see the double-quote at the JSON keys.